# What to do when airline does not update you regarding refunds?

Tags: covid-19, refunds, air-china

Back in February I cancelled a flight I booked with AirChina and asked for a refund due to COVID-19 cases. I would know later that my refund request was processed on March and I was informed, presumably like all the other people who asked for a refund, that the money should arrive to my bank account within two months.

After two months, they told me I should ask my bank to check for the transaction associated to the refund. The bank tells me they know nothing about this.

A few weeks after that, AirChina admitted that because of some technical problem, the refunds on March failed.

When I asked for more information on when the refund will arrive, the person who replied tried to pass me around departments by saying that they are the sales department and not the refund department. I told them to give me the contact of their refund department, but they told me that those contact details are not for the public.

I asked them to ask the refund department on my behalf and I haven't heard since.

I don't have so much experience with what companies do in this situation but I can't help but speculate that they are intentionally "delaying" the refund until people get tired of following up. Perhaps I'm wrong, but I would like to know what else I can do.

Does anyone have any idea on what I should do next? Is there something else I can do to get my money back?

Comment: Did you pay for the tickets using a credit card? If so, then contact your credit card issuer.

Comment: When did you buy the tickets and using what payment mode? How did they say they would refund you? Back to the original card, if you used one? Or did they ask for bank account details for a bank transfer?

Comment: As a note, they are probably not only delaying in hopes that you give up - they likely *have to* delay because they simply don't have the cash to refund everybody impacted by COVID, at least not immediately. We have seen the same pattern with European airlines. It's not so dissimilar to asking a friend for 5000$ back - if they make excuses it may be because they are trying to sit it out, but it may also be that they simply don't have 5000$ they could give you.

Comment: I paid online using a debit card.

Comment: And they said they would give it back to me through that card.

Comment: @xLeitix or both!